# Colorbox Iframe - Different width at different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I am using Jack Moore's Colorbox for a popup and wish to have the colorbox iframe overlay be at 65% width on desktop and 95% width on mobile devices.

I am trying to figure out how to do this. I tried this code, but it didn't work. Am I on the right track?

```
function myFunction(x) {
if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
colorbox.iframe.width = "95%";
} else {
colorbox.iframe.width = "65%";
}
}
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: Can you set up a running example as a snippet?  You can use this cdn to get colorbox: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.colorbox

Comment: Is the colorbox variable properly scoped? If it's not a global variable, your function will just see it as undefined.

Comment: Sorry....I know HTML and CSS well....but not JS and jQuery.  I don't know what it means "properly scoped".  I have script at the bottom of the page that begins, "  $(document).ready(function(){
   //Aassign the Colorbox event to elements
   $(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe:true, width:"95%", height:"95%",
  })
  });